# find deleted records

Tags: sql, django, pandas

I have a Django application that processes a weekly CSV dump of 1.5 years of data and stores it in a PostgreSQL database. The data contains a primary key column and an uploadDate column, among other columns. If a record is deleted from the source, the new dump won't have this record, but the record will exist in my database. I want to use pandas or sql to sort the data by uploadDate in ascending order and compare the records from the older file with the next consecutive one. If there are records in the old file that do not exist in the next one, it means those records were deleted.

How can I solve this using sql or python pandas? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEsmI.png)

```
import pandas as pd
```

def find_deleted_records(df: pd.DataFrame, primary_key: str, upload_date: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
"""
Find records that were deleted from a database table based on a weekly CSV dump.

```
Args:
    df (pd.DataFrame): The dataframe containing the table data.
    primary_key (str): The name of the primary key column.
    upload_date (str): The name of the upload date column.

Returns:
    pd.DataFrame: A dataframe containing the deleted records.

"""
# Sort the data by Peildatum in ascending order
data = df.sort_values(by=upload_date)

# Group the data by Uniek kenmerk and get the first and last Peildatum for each group
grouped_data = data.groupby(primary_key).agg({upload_date: ['first', 'last']})

# Identify the records that were deleted
deleted_records = []
for index, row in grouped_data.iterrows():
    first_Peildatum = row[upload_date]['first']
    last_Peildatum = row[upload_date]['last']
    mask = (data[primary_key] == index) & (data[upload_date] > first_Peildatum) & (data[upload_date] < last_Peildatum)
    if len(data.loc[mask]) == 0:
        deleted_records.append({primary_key: index, upload_date: last_Peildatum})

# Return the deleted records as a dataframe
return pd.DataFrame(deleted_records)
```